# PhantomJS driver is not clicking on element in page, but no errors thrown

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

Lately I have faced on issue with latest phantomjs driver and selenium in java development, so issue is this , we have a web site with list of users where every line of user have a delete button which have js action onclick(). What we are trying to do is to simply remove user, but it is not working on phantomjs, but works perfectly on chrome driver. Note that after clicking on delete button js alert is shown with yes/no, so it must be accepted also.
So here is our current code:

```
FindBy(css = ".glyphicon.glyphicon-trash.text-blue")
private WebElement customerRemoveButton;
.
.
.
.
Actions mouseAction = new Actions(driver);
mouseAction.moveToElement(customerRemoveButton);
mouseAction.click();
mouseAction.build().perform();
acceptAlert();
```

driver is properly initialised  (cause obviously for chrome driver it is working perfectly), note that we already tried with clicking on button with JS Executor of webdriver and ofc with click().

So, when we execute it via chrome, user successfully removed, when via phantomjs test is passing without any single issue, but user is not removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phantom JS something act weirdly. Check if you have a overlay of custom element over html element. if so try to click on custom element and not on actual html element.

if it doesn't work try to click using Javascript, that is you best bet.

Comment: can you add the code of the website, or if it's public can you share the URL and details about the element you are trying to click, this would help others to look into the issue.

Comment: Still having issue ?

Comment: Issue gone, after executing JS from the button directly